# @SqlResultSetMapping with ConstructorResult checks for all the field using BeanProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql, entitymanager

I have an old application which uses entity manager with native queries. The entities are annotated with @SqlResultSetMapping and it uses @ConstructorResult. The application was working fine with older version of Hibernate. However, after the update to hibernate 6.2. The application is no longer able to map field.

For example, let's assume I have a native query "`SELECT FIRST_NAME from PERSON`"

And assuming I have an entity

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
   name = "MAPPING_PERSON",
   classes = {
       @ConstructorResult(
               targetClass = PersonPOJO.class,
               columns = {
                     @ColumnResult(name = "FIRST_NAME")
               }
       )
   }
)
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    private Long id;    
    private String firstname;
}
```

And assuming I have a class called PersonPOJO

```
public class PersonPOJO {
    private String firstname;

    public Person(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public String setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
}
```

When I use `entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, "MAPPING_PERSON")`, I get an hibernate instantiation exception, Cannot set field "FIRST_NAME" to instantiate.

I tried to debug and I found out that hibernate is using DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl internally, and that class uses findField method of Class.java